# Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to integrate abs into my app, but I keep getting this error about not being able to inflate com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer. Can anyone help?

"Styles.xml"

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light" />

</resources>
```

"activity_main.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

"Android Manifest.xml"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.e.ffgh"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

"MainActivity.java"

```
package com.e.ffgh;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

> 08-26 06:13:36.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.e.ffgh/com.e.ffgh.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer

**UPDATE:** Slimmed down post. Started a BS project with just the bare minimum. It works on ICS, but still gives me the "Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer" error in Gingerbread or Froyo

Comment: Change `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem occurs whenever I fixed the warning in the ActionBarSherlock library. I didn't think they would make a difference, but apparently they did. I haven't further check what warning i fixed in the library that makes the compile go bad, but I think it is when I Suppressed the warning about "android.R.attr.animationResolution" being deprecated in the IcsProgressBar class. I will look into that later, but the point is, don't mess with the ActionBarSherlock library when you import it.